# How can members change their data on their own?

Tags: civimember

we have CiviCRM installed in WP. We want, that members change there data on their own. Data could be: bank information, email adr, etc.
Is there a solution in place? 
Thanks
Regards
Edgar

Answer (score 2):

If Members are also WP users then let them log in and have access to either a CiviCRM Profile (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/) or a Caldera Form and you should be able to set up the fields you want them to have access to via the form

If Members are NOT WP users then you can send out a Mailing with a checksum link to a Profile so they can make their changes without logging in

Comment: Hello Petednz,  thanks for the answer. I tested the profiles. Great it works. I have onle a issue with the field IBAN in the banking database. I found no way to include it in the profile. I'll search in the forum. Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: If the IBAN field is a custom field on the CONTRIBUTION rather than on the CONTACT then you won't get it showing other than on a Contribution page afaik